# Find the winner of chess event wise

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Nob.png)

i want group the data according to event and find the winner of tournment using pyspark or sql

#spark.sql("select event,winner from chess group by event,winner").show()

dataset link :-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fb4nyOmYfPjFsrR_222tO38_-DYZWDLA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the rules of the tournament and how they break ties? E.g. a player can have more wins overall and still lose a tournament if they lose certain games.

Comment: please post a sample of the data in the question (and not a picture).